# MERN: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.params.id')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, mern

I am learning MERN using 'Pro MERN Stack' by Vasan Subramanian. The book is good but since there are two years since he wrote it, some of his code no longer work due to changes in the modules he uses. I have a problem recently with one part that I have had to change a lot. It is using react-router and for some reason it stop passing parameters between functions (I am a real beginner, so I probably don't really know what I am talking about). OK, the code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import IssueList from './IssueList.jsx';
import IssueEdit from './IssueEdit.jsx';

const contentNode = document.getElementById('contents');
const NoMatch = () => <p>Page Not Found</p>;

const App = props => (
  <div>
    <div className="header">
      <h1>Issue Tracker</h1>
    </div>
    <div className="contents">
      {props.children}
    </div>
    <div className="footer">
      Full source code available at this <a href="https://github.com/vasansr/pro-mern-stack">
      GitHub repository</a>.
    </div>
  </div>
);

App.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const RoutedApp = () => (
  <App>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/issues" />} />
        <Route exact path="/issues" component={IssueList} />
        <Route exact path="/issues/:id" component={IssueEdit} />
        <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </App>
);

ReactDOM.render(<RoutedApp />, contentNode);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

IssueList works perfect with that, but IssueEdit doesn't and display an error as in the subject. Here is the code of IssueEdit:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class IssueEdit extends React.Component {
    // eslint-desable-line
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>This is a placeholder for editing issue {this.props.params.id}.</p>
                <Link to="/issues">Back to issue list</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

IssueEdit.propTypes = {
  params: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

I don't know how to fix it so the {this.props.params.id} will be properly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `match`:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

Comment: Wow, it works. I cannot believe it is as simple as that :D

Comment: EDIT. Ups, I was happy until I have checked the console. The error is still there. IssueEdit displays the ID now, but nothing else can be retrieved. I need all parameters, so I can edit them later.

Comment: I don't know. The issues are in the database and the component IssueList display them properly in a table, but when I click in a link to a particular issue, the IssueEdit component is loaded but nothing is passed to it. I was already trying the original code from the book that supposed to replace the temporary placeholder, but the error is still there. It looks like something is missing between App and RenderedApp functions.

Comment: This is how the whole error looks like:
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `params` is marked as required in `IssueEdit`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in IssueEdit (created by Route)
    in Route (created by RoutedApp)
    in Switch (created by RoutedApp)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by RoutedApp)
    in div (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App (created by RoutedApp)
    in RoutedApp

Comment: And here are links to the original code from the book that I have changed so it could work again: https://github.com/vasansr/pro-mern-stack/blob/08-browser-history/src/App.jsx and https://github.com/vasansr/pro-mern-stack/blob/08-browser-history/src/IssueEdit.jsx

Comment: @qpanas This is not an error, as it clearly states, it's a warning . It's also doesn't make sense to much, unless you are using `this.props.params` somewhere else there

Comment: But I was trying using it in {this.props.params.id} and I am getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.params.id')

Comment: But didn't you said you changed it to `this.props.match.params.id` ?

Comment: Yes, I did as you advised me, and it helped in this particular issue but when I replace the temporary placeholder for editing issue with the code of that component, it doesn't work because the issue data is not  passed from the IssueList table to the IssueEdit for the particular issue

Comment: OK, I have checked what match is doing  ( https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match ) and it is taking the data from the dynamic segments of the path and this is why it is displaying id but nothing else. I need to pass the whole issue information from the list of issues to the editing component so I could review it and edit if required. The problem is somewhere between App and RenderedApp functions.

Comment: In the original code from the book it was working, but because React changed a lot since the code was written, I have to rewrite it, and because I am not experienced in that I have missed something and now the data is not passed from IssueList to IssueEdit